# Raw transaction nonce won't increment until confirmation

Tags: ether, raw-transaction, rpc

I am building transactions manually and have been able to successfully create raw transactions which can be broadcasted to the network.

My problem is, that while I can get a nonce from the web3.getTransactionCount(address) method, this nonce only returns from the latest confirmed transaction meaning I have nonce conflicts when multiple transactions are broadcasted before confirmation of the other.

Has anyone encountered this problem and if so, how did you work around it?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter so it will also consider pending transactions

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address, 'pending');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion however this doesn't stop racing conditions and it is too laggy for high volumes of transactions

Comment: You are right, for a simple system I've used a global variable in javascript. For a more complex system I've used storage in a shared database. None of that solutions is too elegant in a decentralized environment but sometimes you have to pay that kind of price for a high performance system.