# Is the transaction nonce strictly sequential?

Tags: transactions

Do we have to keep track of the nonce/transaction status, if I am creating a couple of quick/parallel transactions. ie Could we skip a number when creating a raw transaction, if the previous one is dropped/rejected.

Comment: No, it must be strictly incremental. See more information here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39790/concurrency-patterns-for-account-nonce

Comment: Its better to handle nonce externally ,for the case of concurrent transactions.The web3.eth.getTransactionCount can be used to retrieve the nonce. But it won't return the exact result due to the pending transactions.

Comment: ok got it. So its kind of same scenario as in managing a unique ID in a centralized system, across clients and have them work offline as well.