# getting error nonce too low , but nonce is proper stuck since one day

Tags: web3js, dapps, ethereumjs, proxy-contracts

I am working with web3.js since sometime now , but now i am stuck with nonce too low error , the nonce is proper also i have checked private key and other addresses , they also seem to proper , however when i call addNum function is gives nonce too low error

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
let tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

var Web3 =  new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/kG4Z6EC5EsknbOqki4mz")); 

let abi = [
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "x",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "addNum",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getSum",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "sum",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
];


let contract = Web3.eth.contract(abi);
let contractAddress = "0xc8fe6f104a5076a8d3b1284cd1a48095d6f5b5cd";
let contractInstance = contract.at(contractAddress);

let defaultAccount = '0x262b76df1dcb6542aa4a19296a824f0fdd1b4b04'; 
let privatekey = 'ba456ad306a69c3830eed33f690e8f5b93e36cea3cd37ed9604f71b95a5ae1e3';



    var num = 2;

    var data = contractInstance.addNum.getData(num);
            sendRaw(data, function(err, hash){
                if(err)
                {
                   console.log("err "+err);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("hash "+hash);
                }
            });



/**
 * Function to signed and call function in solidity  
 * param data
 * return (err, transactionhash)
 */
var count = Web3.eth.getTransactionCount(defaultAccount);

function sendRaw(data, callback) 
{
    var rawTx  = {
        nonce: Web3.toHex(++count),
        from: Web3.toHex(defaultAccount),
        gasLimit: Web3.toHex(300000),
        gasPrice: Web3.toHex(Web3.toWei('20', 'gwei')),
        to: Web3.toHex(contractAddress),
        value: 0,
        data: data
    };
    var privateKey = new Buffer(privatekey, 'hex');
    var transaction = new tx(rawTx);
    transaction.sign(privateKey);
    var serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex');
    Web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(
    '0x' + serializedTx, function(err, result) {
        if(err) 
        {
            callback(err, '');
        } 
        else 
        {
            callback('', result);
        }
    });
}
```

Also i am testing upgradable smart contract so the address is of proxy contract and abi is of logic contract

Comment: Try changing `count++` to `++count`. Otherwise, you'll just keep trying it with the value returned by `Web3.eth.getTransactionCount`, which is the current nonce.

Comment: and why do you use `Web3.toHex` in many place? I think it's not necessary!

Comment: @goodvibration changing to ++ count does not help

Comment: why are you incrementing the count++ , is this the second transaction you are sending? If not, just set nonce to the number returned by `getTransactionCount()`. The blockchain will increment the transaction count for you, when your transaction is mined. Unless you are sending multiple transactions, you don't need to increment anything.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var count = Web3.eth.getTransactionCount(defaultAccount,'pending');
```

You're starting your count at the number of outstanding/pending transactions the node is aware of. That's the wrong queue.

You could start here:

```
var count = Web3.eth.getTransactionCount(defaultAccount);
```

This will drop the next transaction on the nonce that follows the *last known confirmed transaction*.

It's not a good pattern, generally, to rely on the node's transaction count to set the nonce. Ideally, the software client will be aware of every transaction sent from the account and will *know* the correct number without asking.

Have a look over here for more info: [Why does sendSignedTransaction return a tx hash BUT does not post to the Rinkeby network (React, Metamask, web3, infura)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50042/why-does-sendsignedtransaction-return-a-tx-hash-but-does-not-post-to-the-rinkeby)

And here: [Concurrency patterns for account nonce](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39790/concurrency-patterns-for-account-nonce)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Changing to var count = Web3.eth.getTransactionCount(defaultAccount); does not help

Comment: Maybe post your account address and let us know which network it's on. Bottom line is the next nonce needs to be the one that comes after the last confirmed nonce.

Comment: i have updated the code above to with suggested changes , also have now made private key visible , the contracts and address are on testnet , so please feel free to use the code , still stuck with nonce too low

Comment: Also i think although it says nonce too low , it is not related to nonce... there is something silly mistake that i am missing