# Watch pending transaction from all nodes in network

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, txpool

I have two geth nodes in my own private netwrok: `nodeA` and `nodeB`. When iam sending transaction from `nodeA`, i am able to see this transaction in pending pool after call method `txpool.content` if i have access to `nodeA`. But is it possible to get `txpool` from `nodeA` if i have access only to `nodeB`? And how i can watch all pending txpool from all nodes?

Comment: afaik you need both nodes to be synced as 'full nodes'. If you used light to sync them then they won't have access

Answer (score 1):

The transaction pool is something internal to the node. In geth, there is a web3 extension to query it remotely via JSON RPC. See https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/internal/web3ext/web3ext.go (TxPool_JS).

You'll have to directly use JSON RPC (enable with `-rpcapi txpool`):

E.g.:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"txpool_content","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:8545

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"pending":{},"queued":{}}}
```

Complete method list is:

- txpool_content
- txpool_inspect
- txpool_status

Comment: Actually there is methods which iam using now and they just give me pool of my `nodeA`. But i want to retreview pending txs from other nodes too

Comment: Afaik, from outside you can only query it via jsonrpc port.

Answer (score 1):

The nodes can't tell you about transactions they don't know about.

Each node has a transaction pool but there is no guarantee that it's the same list as you might find on another. In fact, network latency guarantees that there will be differences.

Beware of using the transaction pool for app logic. For example, the transaction pool isn't a very good way to work out the nonce for the next transaction: [getting error nonce too low , but nonce is proper stuck since one day](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58810/getting-error-nonce-too-low-but-nonce-is-proper-stuck-since-one-day)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK each node only knows about it's own txpool.

If you want to know where those transactions are stored in geth, you can look for  transactions.rlp inside your node directory.
In case you want to change that file name you can do so by using the following flag:

```
  --txpool.journal value       Disk journal for local transaction to survive node restarts (default: "transactions.rlp")
```

Comment: With eth65, nodes can gossip pool transactions before they get included in blocks.