# RPC 's SendRawTransaction(increased nonce) many times ,only the first transaction in block

Tags: go-ethereum, rpc

I am using infura node (rinkeby), php.

There are 3 transactions I signed with custom nonce (like the solution [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39790/concurrency-patterns-for-account-nonce/40286#40286)) then broadcasted them by `sendRawTransaction` and succeeded.

After above I get 3 transaction hashs.

Though, only the first transaction can be found in block.

Comment: Do you see your other transactions among [pending ones](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/txsPending)?  Could you show us transaction that was successfully included into block?

Comment: Try just waiting between them.  I had that problem, but if I just waited a minute before broadcasting a subsequent transaction it worked

Comment: Did you use incremental and consecutive nonces? For example 4, 5 and 6.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov `0x8f8e34220c0711715d34d44d4379b6c79234f2eb8da331b5121e21c9602bb4cb` the first successed  and  the others `0xe706aa708a3f9e0c83c93d17e4d47912dfa7a5e02b68976fc1d4e8d8a2886b3e`,`0x871228ef50542f15f8dd6837b0a6706dfea3887c302bfeb9961cb5576607bde7` not found in pending but if change to local node I can found in `txpool`, I think @thefett is right so I will change my code work like that

Comment: @thefett I waited until `eth_getTransactionReceipt` returned a transaction ,but the problem still happend

Comment: you'll want to wait even longer.  I usually do 20 seconds, but my theory on the reason is that Infura load balances between nodes.  So even if you're node sends you back a receipt, when you send the next request, it could go to a different node that doesn't know about your transaction yet

Comment: @thefett No you don't need wait. I just  send error transactions with a error nonce signed with `web3p/ethereum-tx`. The `nonce`  **should in hex**. Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it may not be the answer. I found there is just a misstake in signature;

Using `web3p/ethereum-tx` the **nonce should be hex** not integer in nodejs.And every transaction will arrive successfully