# Nonce delays while using different nodes

Tags: nonce, full-node, node-discovery

Question related to the nonce,

In case I am using a scaling solution with few nodes due to massive traffic with many transactions and **submitting a transaction to node X, but the nonce for the next transaction fetched from node Y** (I am speaking about fast-paced transactions submission), which in some cases causes a discrepancy between nonce for the same address (suppose related to time until the transaction reach mempool and known to all network) and of course, it causes failed transaction with “nonce already used/known”.

The transaction serialization is done on the wallet implementation side and sent via RPC eth_sendRawTransaction.

To get the next nonce I am using eth_getTransactionCount.

I saw that one of the solutions was to create a Nonce Manager.

The last time this matter was raised 4 years ago in this [topic](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76855/about-transaction-higher-nonce-than-current-nonce)

Has anyone encountered such cases?

If someone implemented such a solution with a nonce manager can share some tips?

Maybe some advice, docs to read, etc...

It would be much appreciated