# Geth automining includes only 1 transaction per block

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, gas, gas-limit

I am trying to perform a heavy load and scalability tests on a smart contract. However, the test takes a lot of time because only 1 transaction is added per block. I read that this might be due to gasLimit of the block but currently my blocks have a limit of 3877440195466 gas and the transaction that is processed take s "txs=1 gas=36544". I am wondering how can I fix that and also if there is a way to change my mining code so that more transactions are added per block?

Comment: What is your geth command line? Is your network PoA or PoW? What is your genesis file? A geth blockchain can be configured to generate blocks at a fixed interval of time instead of mining immediately.

Comment: @Ismael It is a PoW chain. I believe I found what the problem is but I am not sure how to fix it. Basically, I am testing an ERC20 token and I am trying to perform 500 transactions in a truffle test and measure the time that it would take for all of them to be processed. I was using 'await contract.transfer(..)' for each transaction in order to measure how much time it took for the transaction to be deployed but await causes transactions to be processed 1 by 1. When I removed it , the blocks included multiple transactions but I dont know how to measure the execution time in this case

Comment: Is it possible you are waiting for transaction confirmation before emitting the next transaction? That would indeed result in one transaction per block.

Comment: @Rob Yeah I believe that's the problem. The problem is that I am not sure how I can get confirmation for transactions without await so that I can measure the time it takes for all of them to be processed

Comment: You don't have to wait for confirmation to send the next one, although you should be prepared to deal with the failure case. This might be helpful (I like #2) or maybe skipping ahead too fast. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39790/concurrency-patterns-for-account-nonce

Comment: I was going to show you your other question until I realized it was you. There you are trying to measure confirmation when you're firing off 500 transactions at a time. It should not wait for a block between each one, the way you did it. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79469/measuring-deployment-time-of-a-group-of-transactions-in-a-heavy-load-testing