# Transaction Order of Execution - Same Gas

Tags: transactions, gas

I'm scratching my head here regarding transaction order of execution.  Reference to these posts:

[Order of transactions in the same block](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79907/order-of-transactions-in-the-same-block)

[What is the default ordering of transactions during mining?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-is-the-default-ordering-of-transactions-during-mining)

- Let's say we have two accounts A and B
- Both accounts sends the same kind of transaction with the exact same gas fee
- Which transaction gets executed first?
- Is it random?
- Does the timestamp play a role?
- Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Both the order of transactions between different accounts and the fact if a transaction is even included, are decided by the miner. The miner could even decide to include a lower gasPrice insted of a higher one. The only limitation, as explained in the first post you refered, is that transactions from the same account are processed in nonce order.

Comment: Yes it's decided by the miner, but I'm sure they are using 80% the same algorithm?  How does that algorithm work ?