# Why did my buy (fulfill order) transaction fail and someone else's succeed when I paid more gas and submitted at the exact same time?

Tags: transactions

I am perplexed by this.

Here is my transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7219718ef3ecc3a4bd665a557c56ffce44f17b8ecf0c77900fe9b43d36bd84b5

Here is the other person's: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5cfe53c9fdd7e381157bd12c27bb9f55ce4e38b05822535e6fc62f0b9d6f5829

As you can see I paid more gwei and our time stamps are the same. Is it the different in gas limit? Someone please help me understand, thanks..

Comment: As explained here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79907/order-of-transactions-in-the-same-block, the miners have freedom to decide the transaction order inside a block. There's nothing in the protocol that forces them to sort in a particular way. Moreover there's flashbot project that provides miners extra incentives for including transactions in an arbitrary order.

Answer (score 0):

this is the thing called front running.
what way did you choose to set the gas price and the gas limit with opensea-js?