# Resubmitting the same transaction

Tags: dapps, dapp-design

A common concern for dapps using public blockchains is to check that a submitted transaction was included in a block after some time. And, if not, try to resubmit the same transaction (I mean, using the same nonce, perhaps with a higher gas price).
Does anyone have recommendations/existing code to solve this issue? Ideally in Angular or React.

Comment: resubmitting transaction will not help anyhow. You will get an error message, that this transaction was already seen

Comment: If you reuse the nonce and use higher gas price, the old transaction will essentially be replaced. This shouldn't cause any errors

Comment: Agree, @LauriPeltonen

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at candidate 3 over here. [Concurrency patterns for account nonce](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39790/concurrency-patterns-for-account-nonce?r=SearchResults)

This is a pretty important issue for any account that sends a lot of transactions since one underpriced transaction blocks all transactions that follow it.

In any such case, monitor confirmation and have a plan to resolve any stuck transactions.

Hope it helps.